# How do I reset the value of the file input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I reset `this.fileInput` to empty or null or undefined?

```
class FileInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.fileInput = React.createRef();  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`Selected file - ${this.fileInput.current.files[0].name}`);
    // Assume I have uploaded the file here
    // How do I reset this.fileInput to empty Ref?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Upload file:
          <input type="file" ref={this.fileInput} />        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FileInput />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input type="reset"

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
      Upload file:
      <input type="file" ref={this.fileInput} /></label>
    <br />
    <input type="reset" defaultValue="Reset" />  
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually trying to "reset" the form, so you should call [`HTMLFormElement.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

```
export default class FileInput extends React.Component {
  fileInput = React.createRef();
  formRef = React.createRef();

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`Selected file - ${this.fileInput.current.files[0].name}`);
    this.formRef.current.reset();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form ref={this.formRef} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Upload file:
          <input type="file" ref={this.fileInput} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit nostalgic-napier-p1cvw]

Answer (score 0):

just clear the value of your ref

```
this.fileInput.current.value = ''
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have to reset it immediately after I assign it to a new variable e.g. 

```
alert(`Selected file - ${this.fileInput.current.files[0].name}`);
const file = this.fileInput.current.files[0];
this.fileInput.current.value = '';
```

If I do anything in between the assignment and then reset, I get an error, "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null" e.g.

```
alert(`Selected file - ${this.fileInput.current.files[0].name}`);
const file = this.fileInput.current.files[0];
// do something here, e.g. process file
this.fileInput.current.value = '';
```

Comment: Just figure it out. The `// do something here` I was doing was calling an async function, which according to Mozilla docs:

"Code after each await expression can be thought of as existing in a .then callback. In this way a promise chain is progressively constructed with each reentrant step through the function."

Therefore, considering **createRef** creates a new reference, I've instead replaced it with **useRef** (which persists) and now it works fine. Thanks for the help.